# HR-XML database schema

Tags: xml, database-design, database-schema

We'd like to follow HR-XML standards when designing database for our project. Does anyone have a ready-to-use relational DB schema that represents HR-XML entities?

Comment: Generating a relational Database Schema from a complex XML Schema is never a nice prospect, however there are some automated tools that can help you with this. Should you want to perform queries across the XML tree, performance can be highly variable if you have not already defined indexes. You might like to consider instead using a Native XML Database, or as a 1/2 way house using SQL/XML capabilities of databases like Oracle RDBMS which can auto-generate tables from XML Schema and shred XML into them.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with gpx (which is also an XML format). Here is how I proceeded then :

- Import the XSD into [Entreprise Achitect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/).
- Use the nice diagram as basis of the database design.

I do not have a good command of the tool but getting a good picture suffices to me as a starting point.